# Not displaying username on the profile section arrived from google firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is the code of of my "profile.html"

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-app.js";

import { getStorage, 
    ref, uploadBytes, 
    getDownloadURL } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-storage.js";

import { getDatabase } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-database.js";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-auth.js"; // Initialize Firebase

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBiydb9tqJp526GBYwTqv3S7P_ErmOntLg",
    authDomain: "mom-login-a6e00.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://mom-login-a6e00-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "mom-login-a6e00",
    storageBucket: "mom-login-a6e00.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "14987956774",
    appId: "1:14987956774:web:f55080976493fa99a20ce7"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); // Logout button /\*

var logoutBtn = document.getElementById("logoutBtn");

logoutBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () { // Sign-out successful. 
        window.location.href = "login.html";
    }).catch(function (error) { // An error happened. 
        console.error(error);
    });
}); // Check if user is logged in

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) { // User is signed in. 
        var emailSpan = document.getElementById("email"); emailSpan.textContent = user.email;
    } else { // User is not signed in.\`your text\`
        window.location.href = "login.html";
    }
});
```

I created login.html and registration.html with firebase and they worked fine, now I want to get the data from firebase and display in the profile.html

Comment: Please could you format your code as this isn't all that readable.

Comment: @EliNathan now kindly check again

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly how you'll show the data without seeing your HTML.

It looks like you're grabbing elements by their ID with `document.getElementById` so you'll need a HTML element for each of the properties you're trying to display.

If you're not sure what properties the user object has you could either look at the docs or try doing a `console.log(user)` when you determine that the user is logged in like so:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) { // User is signed in. 
        var emailSpan = document.getElementById("email");
        emailSpan.textContent = user.email;

        // LOG USER PROPERTIES HERE
        console.log('user', user)
    } else { // User is not signed in.\`your text\`
        window.location.href = "login.html";
    }
});
```

The user should have some/all of the properties listed in the [Firebase docs for the user property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#properties).

From there you can just add each of the properties to another element on the page:

```js
var emailSpan = document.getElementById("email");
emailSpan.textContent = user.email;

var displayNameSpan = document.getElementById("displayName");
emailSpan.textContent = user.displayName;

// And so on...
```

I would say that manipulating HTML in this way can get super hard to maintain. I'd suggest using one of the many JS frameworks like [ReactJS](https://react.dev/), [Angualr](https://angular.io/) or [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/) to help with this.